# How to merge two csv files that do not have the same number of lines?

Tags: python, csv, merge

Below is my two csv files:

```
CSV1:


Class   DTWC    DR  DW  IDFP    IDS ISQLQ   IGS LIC LT  MIM NLMR    PD  RAM SL  UC  LazyClass
com.onegravity.colorpicker.demo.MainActivity    0   0   0    0  0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0
com.onegravity.colorpicker.demo.SettingsActivity    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
com.onegravity.colorpicker.AlphaPatternDrawable 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0
com.onegravity.colorpicker.ColorPickerDialog    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

CSV2:


Push Down Attribute Move Class  Rename Class    Move and Rename Class Extract and Move Method   Move Source Folder  Change Package  Extract Variable Rename Attribute   Move and Rename Attribute    Replace Variable with Attribute Replace Attribute  Merge Variable  Merge  Parameter    Merge Attribute split Variable  split Parameter Split  Attribute    Class
0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 0 0   0   0   0   0   0         com.onegravity.colorpicker.AlphaPatternDrawable
```

I need to merge them so I used this code :

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv("filea.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("fileb.csv")
b = b.dropna(axis=1)
merged = a.merge(b, on='Class')
merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

The problem that the second csv file doesn't contain all the classes, it contains just one class so I need to merge the second csv in the third line and put 0 in the rest.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some of the options to the [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) command.

In this instance...

```
merged = a.merge(b, on='Class', how='left')
```

The `how='left'`  means that only keys present in the "left" data frame are kept.

The rows other than those that match will have missing values so you will want to then use the fillna() to replace them with zero

```
merged = merged.fillna(0)
```

...before you write to CSV.

Comment: You're welcome, bookmark the Pandas documentation its invaluable.  For merging data in all sorts of different manners you may find [Merge, join, and concatenate — pandas 0.24.2 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) particularly useful.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is that you are trying to read a CSV without indicating the separator. Which by default is ',' but you are using spaces. This is solved using the `sep='\s+'` option while reading the file.

The other problem is the name of each column. You don't have the same attribute `Class` in both files. We can fix this with `left_on` and `right_on` arguments.

```
import pandas as pd
a = pd.read_csv("filea.csv", sep='\s+')
b = pd.read_csv("fileb.csv", sep='\s+')
b = b.dropna(axis=1)
merged = a.merge(b, how='outer', left_on='Class', right_on='Attribute.2')
merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```